# ANOVA F-test shows significant differences among treatments, but HSD.test does not: What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Tags: r, anova, normality-assumption, tukey-hsd-test

I am working with a dataset (in R) that has been hierarchically-clustered into three distinct clusters. My goal is to conduct a one-way analysis of variance to see if there are any statistical differences among groups. While I cannot share the data due to confidentiality restrictions, I can say that each of the 3 groups has 50 measurements within it.

After checking assumptions, I did a log transformation on the original data to make it more normal (without transformation, data did not pass the Shapiro-Wilks test for normallity). Running an ANOVA on the data (for each of the groups) shows that there are significant differences between the groups. Note that all significance levels were set at 0.05:

```
Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: score_log
          Sum Sq  Df F value  Pr(>F)  
cluster   0.1190   1  5.4186 0.02125 *
Residuals 3.3175 151
```

However, when running an HSD.test with the `agricolae` package in R (again with alpha equal to 0.05), there shows to be no significant difference among groups:

```
$groups
  score   groups
1  2.86      a
2  2.83      a
3  2.78      a
```

As a reminder, I ran the ANOVA on the **transformed data**, as the normality of assumption was satisfied.

Looking at a graph of the means of the **original data** (aggregated per cluster group), there does appear to be significant differences between the groups. Error bars above the graph depict standard error:

[image]

**Are there any reasons for this HSD.test not separating out the means?** I find this strange that the Anova would be significantly different, but the HSD.test would not be.

Comment: HSD uses a different criterion than F or t tests. HSD is based on the distribution of the maximum difference in means among the $k$ levels of the factor. With P-value about 0.02 the significance of the main effect is not really strong, so a different criterion may not see significances among pairs of levels. Happens rarely, but (as you have seen) not impossible.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!